# Convert a Date and Time selected by user to timestamp

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, timestamp

Can someone let me know how do you convert a User selected `Date` and `Time` to `Timestamp` value? Preferably `UNIX` timestamp.

Comment: Can you tell, In which format the date and time it is?

Comment: MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code for convert `Date` and `Time` to `Unix Timestamp` (for `datetime` format `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`)

```
try {
        Date utilDate;
        SimpleDateFormat sqlDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String sqlDate = "2014-01-01 10:10:10";
        Calendar calTempDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        calTempDate.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
        utilDate = sqlDateFormat.parse(sqlDate);
        calTempDate.setTime(utilDate);
        long dt = (calTempDate.getTimeInMillis()) / 1000;
        System.out.println("Timestamp is: " + dt);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```